# How to calculate count?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, count

I want to calculate the count data from data table `dt` based on time and I have to store the counts on different variables.

**Sample DB :**

```
ID   File_Name    Uploaded_Time
-----   ---------    -------------
1         abc       3/18/2015 12:03:26 AM
1         abc       3/18/2015 12:10:26 AM
1         abc       3/18/2015 1:47:26 AM
1         abc       3/18/2015 2:17:52 AM
2         abc       3/18/2015 3:55:26 AM
1         abc       3/18/2015 6:12:44 AM
2         abc       3/18/2015 8:55:26 AM
2         abc       3/18/2015 10:55:26 AM
2         abc       3/18/2015 11:49:26 AM
1        abc       3/18/2015 12:55:26 PM
1        abc       3/18/2015 1:47:26 PM
1        abc       3/18/2015 2:47:26 PM
1        abc       3/18/2015 4:23:15 PM
1        abc       3/18/2015 6:47:26 PM
2        abc       3/18/2015 8:33:45 PM
```

**Code :**

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

 CommunicationTableAdapters.tbl_splited_detailsTableAdapter sd;
 sd = new CommunicationTableAdapters.tbl_splited_detailsTableAdapter();
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt = sd.GetSiteUploadDetails(ddlSiteID.SelectedValue, txtDate.Text);
 foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
   {
     if (dt.Rows.IndexOf(row) != 0)
      {
        string uplodedtime = (row["Uploaded_Time"].ToString());
      }
   }
}
```

**Example :**

Calculate the count in between 12:00:00 AM to 1:00:00 AM and store in a variable. Like this I want to calculate 24 hrs count and store in 24 variable.

From the above sample DB, the required output is

```
variable  count
--------  -----
hour1       2
hour2       1
hour3       1
hour4       1
hour5       0
hour6       0
hour7       1
hour8       0
hour9       1
hour10      0
hour11      1
hour12      1
hour13      1
hour14      1
hour15      1
hour16      0
hour17      1
hour18      0
hour19      1
hour20      0
hour21      1
hour22      0
hour23      0
hour24      0
```

Comment: Create an array of int with 24 elements, accumulate to to array[hour_of_date] in your loop

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var result = 
       dt.AsEnumerable()
          .GroupBy (x => x.Field<DateTime>("Uploaded_Time").Hour)
          .Select (x => new { Hour = x.Key, Count = x.Count() });
```

And if you want to to get a `0` for non existing values use the above expression with:

```
result = from hour in Enumerable.Range(0, 24)
         join item in result on hour equals item.Hour into g
         from item in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new
         {
            Hour = hour == 0 ? 24 : hour,
            Count = item == null ? 0 : item.Count
          };
```

Comment: @GrantWinney True, but this should point him in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Since the data is already sorted on the basis of upload time so what you could do is take 5 variables and read each query from the upload time colm.

- 1st var mon = string till first '/'
- 2nd var day = string between first '/' and second '/'
- 3 rd var for year
- 4th variable for the hour time
- and 5 th variable for a look ahead hour time

So in your ques it would be for first query

```
day = 18
mon =  3
year = 2015
hour_initial = 12
hour_ahead = 12
```

and increment count till the hour_ahead changes or the day changes.(which ever comes first) and upload count for that specific hour

Then change the hour_intial to next hour and continue the process.....
(this is the basic technique)